# GROUP BY returning more than ONE row MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

TABLE IMAGE: 
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BRxu.png)

I need to sum all the values from **total_serviços** (annual revenue from 2019) from a determined cmc_emissor the cmc_emissor values is the same to all rows

Here is my code and the result:

```
SELECT year(emissao) as 'Periodo', cmc_emissor, sum(total_serviços) as 'Total'
FROM nfpse
GROUP BY cmc_emissor, emissao
HAVING cmc_emissor = 'E000000';
```

Result: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pg4X.png)

Expected result:  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFsub.png)

Comment: The cmc_emissor value is the same for all rows

Comment: Is emissao is a coloumn or table name?

Comment: You don't need a group by if cmc_emissor is the selected and the year is selected - just a where clause - without a group by the aggregates will be over the whole result set. - unless the point of the homework is to use group by..

Comment: use group by what is selected in query you have selected year(emissao) and group by only GROUP BY cmc_emissor, emissao how that is possible  both have to be same

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cmc_emissor, year(emissao) as 'Periodo',
       sum(total_serviços) as 'Total'
FROM nfpse
WHERE cmc_emissor = 'E000000'
GROUP BY cmc_emissor, year(emissao)
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'emissao' in 'having clause'

Comment: or even `GROUP BY cmc_emissor, Periodo HAVING Periodo = 2019`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Year(emissao) in your group by clause it is matching the complete date including days and months and hence giving multiple results.

```
SELECT year(emissao) as 'Periodo', cmc_emissor, sum(total_serviços) as 'Total'
FROM nfpse
GROUP BY cmc_emissor, YEAR(emissao)
HAVING year(emissao) = '2019';
```

[SQL Documentation Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

[Year() Function Documentation SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)